# trying to make a schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a schema of a (course) which is this:

```
  targetNamespace="http://www.nova.edu/course"
  xmlns="http://www.nova.edu/course"
  xmlns:ins="http://www.nova.edu/instructor"
  xmlns:mat="http://www.nova.edu/materials"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  >
  <xs:import schemaLocation="InstructorSchema.xsd" namespace="http://www.nova.edu/instructor" />
  <xs:import schemaLocation="MaterialsSchema.xsd" namespace="http://www.nova.edu/materials" />

  <xs:element name="course">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="title"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="program"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:short" name="number"/>
        <xs:element name="term">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:int" name="crn"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:int" name="code"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:short" name="year"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="schedule">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="dates">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:date" name="startdate"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:date" name="enddate"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="day"/>
              <xs:element name="time">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="starttime"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="endtime"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="location">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="building"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:short" name="room"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element ref="ins:instructor" />
        <xs:element ref="mat:materials" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

now am trying to Create a new schema that defines a Courses element that is a collection of zero or more (course) elements.

```
targetNamespace="http://www.nova.edu/allcourses"
  xmlns="http://www.nova.edu/allcourses"
  xmlns:cor="http://www.nova.edu/course"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  >
    <xs:import schemaLocation="CourseSchema.xsd" namespace="http://www.nova.edu/course" />

     <xs:element name="courses">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="course" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

am not sure if I should add more elements in my new schema in order for it to work well. The idea is just to be able have multiple courses and each course is based on the (course)schema above.

Comment: Consider alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

In your `courses` element, use

```
<xs:element ref="course" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```

to refer to the existing declaration of element `course`, rather than redefining it locally.